# Importing text file into R that has spaces that are not new columns

Tags: r, read.table

I have a text file from NOAA that has a list of weather stations there should he 8 columns, with no header. They are all separated by spaces but in the cases below some have a name like "ABBEVILLE" others "ANDALUSIA 3 W". When I read this into R with read.table I get 10 columns.

USC00010008  31.5702  -85.2482  139.0 AL ABBEVILLE 15  -6

USC00010252  31.3071  -86.5226 76.2 AL ANDALUSIA 3 W  15 -6

```
precip_stations <- read.table("hpd-stations.txt", sep = "", header = FALSE, fill = T) 

> V1           V2       V3     V4  V5     V6    V7  V8 V9  V10
>USC00010008 31.5702 -85.2482 139  AL ABBEVILLE 15  -6
>USC00010252 31.3071 -86.5226 76.2 AL ANDALUSIA  3  W  15  -6
```

Is there a way I can get it to import things like "ANDALUSIA 3 W" in one column? I thought that fill = FALSE might work but if I do that I get an error.

Comment: Read in with `readLines` and pre-process by using regex to insert quotes. Then pass to `read.table`. However, I'm guessing those were really fixed width formated files before you started working with them and it would have been easier to keep them that way and use `read.fwf`

Comment: It's also possible that it was a tab delimited file.  Does using `sep = \t` change the import at all?

Comment: \t puts it all in one column and I have not changed anything in the downloaded file from NOAA

Comment: Here is a link to the file [link](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/hpd/auto/v1/beta/hpd-stations.txt)

Comment: SEE? it IS a FWF file. Please read my earlier comment again and again until it's value sinks in.

Answer (score 1):

Reading fixed width format files requires that you first recognize there are no valid separators, then using `read.fwf. That in turn requires that you determine the spacing to calculate the widths:

```
inp <- "
USC00010008  31.5702  -85.2482  139.0 AL ABBEVILLE                                                                                 15    -6
USC00010063  34.2553  -87.1814  249.3 AL ADDISON                                                                                   15    -6"
> cat( paste0( rep( 0:9, 13), collapse=""))
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
```

Note that proper text editors may sometimes help with a "ruler". I sometimes make a ruler with:

```
cat( paste0( rep( c(1:9,0), 7), collapse="")); cat("\n"); 
cat(paste0( sprintf( "% 10s", 1:7), collapse=""))
#---------------------------------------
#1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
#         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
```

In fact, I've just realized I should be making a function that creates an adjustable ruler:

```
ruler <- function(len=7){ cat( paste0( rep( c(1:9,0), len), collapse=""))
                          cat("\n")
                          cat(paste0( sprintf( "% 10s", 1:len), collapse="")) }
> ruler(13)  # could not get a proper display of the output in SO
```

(Now saved to my .Rprofile suite of utility functions.)

Then with a guess at the widths and a couple of adjustments after this error:

```
> read.fwf(textConnection(inp), widths=c(10, 10,10, 7, 90, 5, 5) )
          V1         V2       V3    V4                                                                                         V5 V6 V7
1       <NA>       <NA>       NA    NA                                                                                       <NA> NA NA
2 USC0001000 8  31.5702 -85.2482 139.0  AL ABBEVILLE                                                                               1  5
3 USC0001006 3  34.2553 -87.1814 249.3  AL ADDISON                                                                                 1  5
```

I finally got:

```
 myfwf <- readLines("ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/hpd/auto/v1/beta/hpd-stations.txt" )
> mytbl <- read.fwf(textConnection(myfwf[1:12]), widths=c(11, 10,10, 7, 89, 5, 5) )
> mytbl
            V1      V2       V3    V4                                                                                        V5 V6 V7
1  USC00010008 31.5702 -85.2482 139.0 AL ABBEVILLE                                                                               1  5
2  USC00010063 34.2553 -87.1814 249.3 AL ADDISON                                                                                 1  5
3  USC00010140 32.2322 -87.4104  53.3 AL ALBERTA                                                                                 1  5
4  USC00010252 31.3071 -86.5226  76.2 AL ANDALUSIA 3 W                                                                           1  5
5  USC00010369 33.2941 -85.7788 311.5 AL ASHLAND 3 ENE                                                                           1  5
6  USC00010390 34.7752 -86.9508 210.0 AL ATHENS                                                                                  1  5
7  USC00010402 31.1820 -87.4390  91.4 AL ATMORE                                                                                  1  5
8  USC00010425 32.5992 -85.4653 166.1 AL AUBURN NO.2                                                                             1  5
9  USC00010748 33.6972 -87.6491 157.9 AL BERRY 3 NW                                                                              1  5
10 USC00010957 34.2008 -86.1633 326.1 AL BOAZ                                                                                    1  5
11 USC00011099 34.9786 -85.8008 204.2 AL BRIDGEPORT 5 NW                                                                         1  5
12 USC00012124 32.8622 -85.7358 223.4 AL DADEVILLE 2                                                                             1  5
```

Notice that I restricted that to the first 12 lines because line 13 had an octothorpe ("#") which results in premature line termination since that is the R comment character.

```
USC00012172  30.2505  -88.0775    2.4 AL DAUPHIN ISLAND #2                                                                         15    -6
```

So need `comment.char=""`:

```
> mytbl <- read.fwf(textConnection(myfwf), widths=c(11, 10,10, 7, 89, 5, 5) , comment.char="")
> str(mytbl)
'data.frame':   1920 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 1920 levels "CQC00914080",..: 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 ...
 $ V2: num  31.6 34.3 32.2 31.3 33.3 ...
 $ V3: num  -85.2 -87.2 -87.4 -86.5 -85.8 ...
 $ V4: num  139 249.3 53.3 76.2 311.5 ...
 $ V5: Factor w/ 1920 levels "AK CENTRAL NO 2                                                                          ",..: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 ...
 $ V6: Factor w/ 9 levels "    1","0   1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V7: Factor w/ 2 levels "5    ","5   -": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Nicely done. And you can add `mytbl$V5 <- trimws(mytbl$V5)` to remove the white space in `V5` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but works:

```
x <- readLines("hpd-stations.txt")

l <- list()

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  a <- strsplit(x[i], " ")
  b <- t(sapply(a, "[", 1:5))
  c <- length(a[[1]]) - 5 - 2
  d <- t(sapply(a, "[", 6:(5+c)))
  e <- t(sapply(a, "[", (5+c+1):length(a[[1]])))
  res <- as.data.frame(cbind(b, paste0(d, collapse = " "), e))
  l[[i]] <- res
}

data <- dplyr::bind_rows(l)
```

Gives you

```
> data
           V1      V2       V3  V4 V5              V6 V7 V8
1 USC00010008 31.5702 -85.2482 139 AL       ABBEVILLE 15 -6
2 USC00010009 31.5602 -85.2482 179 AL ABBEVILLFOO 3 W 15 -6
```

Tested with dummy data.

EDIT: Just saw that a link to the file appeared. Haven't tested with that, but you should consider using `read.fwf()` anyway now.

Comment: @Jeffkrop: Almost there. See the need to suppress the default comment character.